# Wordpress post text starts newline after 93 characters

Tags: posts, text, line-breaks

When typing the text of a new post, my text stops halfway the textarea and starts on a new line again. There are no linebreaks after a cut-ff sentence.

When I type a single line of characters the Wordpress starts a new line after 93 characters.

See the attached image to see how it looks.

[image]

Comment: If you click the **Text** tab, are there `<br />` tags inserted in the text?  If not, this is likely just a style that's applied to the TinyMCE editor textarea to make your text easier to read in the editor view.

Comment: Jup, that was it. But why don't I see any `<p>` or `<br/>` tags when on the **Text** tab? As you can see in the image there are paragraphs shown on the **Visual** tab.

Comment: The Text tab is not a pure HTML representation - by default, single line breaks are converted to `<br />` and doubles are converted to `<p>` on display.

Comment: Is there a way to show a sort of **Source** tab where I can directly manipulate the HTML of the post? The reason I ask, is because when I look in the Wordpress database I don't see the `<br/>` and `<p>` tags in the `post_content` column...

Comment: The **Text** tab *is* the HTML view; you can add in <br /> and <p> tags there, and they'll be respected (depending on what your plugins and theme might do with the `the_content` filter, that is).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the visual editor in your User Profile and see if that helps. If it does, disable any plugins - *always one of the first troubleshooting tips to try with WordPress* - that have anything to do with the editor functions and enable the Visual Editor again and see if the text is still hard wrapping.

And, it's always a good idea to check Developer Tools in your browser, too, to look for any javascript errors that will impact the editor. Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Commenter on initial post solved it, it was in the CSS, however, I still do not understand why I don't see any `<p>` or `<br/>` tags when on the **Text** tab? As you can see in the image there are paragraphs shown on the **Visual** tab

Comment: @Flo : Paragraph tags are added on _display_ by `wpautop`.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, since I'm integrating it with an ASP.NET application and doing direct queries to the database. Is there a way for Wordpress to generate these tags at design/edit time instead and have that stored in the database?